# Elasticsearch - query dates without a specified timezone

Tags: date, elasticsearch, timezone

I have an index with the following mappings - standard format for a date.  In the 2nd record below the time specified is actually a local time - but ES treats it as UTC.

Even though ES is internally converting all parsed datetimes to UTC but it must obviously store the original string as well.

My question is whether (and how) it might be possible to query all records for which the scheduledDT value doesn't have the timezone explicitly specified.

```
{
   "curator_v3": {
      "mappings": {
         "published": {
            "analyzer": "classic",
            "numeric_detection": true,
            "properties": {
               "Id": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "include_in_all": false
               },
               "createDT": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                  "include_in_all": false
               },
               "scheduleDT": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime",
                  "include_in_all": false
               },
               "title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "fields": {
                     "english": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "english"
                     },
                     "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                     },
                     "shingle": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "shingle"
                     },
                     "spanish": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "spanish"
                     }
                  },
                  "include_in_all": false
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

We use .NET as our client to ElasticSearch and haven't been consistent in specifying a timezone for the scheduleDT field.

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 12,
      "successful": 12,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 32,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "curator_v3",
            "_type": "published",
            "_id": "29651227",
            "_score": null,
            "fields": {
               "Id": [
                  "29651227"
               ],
               "scheduleDT": [
                  "2015-11-21T22:17:51.0946798-06:00"
               ],
               "title": [
                  "97 Year-Old Woman Cries Tears Of Joy After Finally Getting Her High School Diploma"
               ],
               "createDT": [
                  "2015-11-21T22:13:32.3597142-06:00"
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               1448165871094
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "curator_v3",
            "_type": "published",
            "_id": "210466413",
            "_score": null,
            "fields": {
               "Id": [
                  "210466413"
               ],
               "scheduleDT": [
                  "2015-11-22T12:00:00"
               ],
               "title": [
                  "6 KC treats to bring to Thanksgiving"
               ],
               "createDT": [
                  "2015-11-20T15:08:25.4282-06:00"
               ]
            },
            "sort": [
               1448193600000
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "ScheduleDT": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 27,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 1448165871094,
               "key_as_string": "2015-11-22T04:17:51.094Z",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": 1448193600000,
               "key_as_string": "2015-11-22T12:00:00.000Z",
               "doc_count": 4
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by querying the document having a `scheduleDT` whose field length is less than 20 characters (e.g. `2015-11-22T12:00:00`). All the date fields with a specified time zone would be longer.

Something like this should do:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "doc.scheduleDT.value.size() < 20"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note, however, that in order to make your queries easier to create you should always try to convert all your timestamps in UTC **before** indexing your documents.

Finally, also make sure that you have [dynamic scripting enabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order to run the above query.

**UPDATE**

Actually, if you use the `_source` directly in the script it will work because it will return the real value from the source as it was when the document was indexed:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "_source.scheduleDT.size() < 20"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Brillant Val.  Hadn't considered treating the value as a string.

I did have to change your script slightly to:

doc.scheduleDT.value.toString().size() < 20

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry about that, glad you figured it out.

Comment: I had enough data to convert so I didn't immediately notice this but the 'value' being compared to 20 characters seems to be underlying representation of the date (i.e. 1448320714367) rather than the string equivalent (i.e. 2015-11-23T17:18:34.367949-06:00)

I've tried various ways to return the same string representation displayed in the results and use that to check the length - but haven't found a means of doing so yet.

Comment: This script seems to get closer to representing the date as a string - but consistently formats it as UTC regardless of whether the date originally had an offset. **new DateTime(doc.createDT.value).toString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ')**...  The date 2015-11-23T**17**:18:34.367949-06:00 is output as 2015-11-23 **23**:18:34+0000   while the date 2014-10-15T**15**:35:03.34 is output as 2014-10-15 **15**:35:03+0000.... So ES clearly understands the 1st date had a timezone and the 2nd one didn't.

Comment: Perfect.  Really appreciate the follow-up Val.